# gathering stats for supreme community website

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get the stats for the Title, Price, and Upvotes/Downvotes off of the supreme community website by using the Scrapy library in Python.

```
import scrapy


class SupremeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Supreme"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2019/droplist/2019-02-25/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css('div.card-details'):
            yield {
                'title': data.xpath("//h2/text()").getall(),
                'price': data.css('span.label-price::text').get()     
                #'upvotes': data.xpath("//p/text()").getall()
                #'downvotes': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }
```

when i run scrapy crawl Supreme in CMD:

the result looks like this:

> 2019-02-27 14:19:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200
>   https://www.supremecommunity.com/season/spring-summer2019/droplist/2019-02-25/>
>   {'title': ['Airbrushed Floral Skateboard', 'Formula Crewneck',
>   'Supreme®/Master Lock® Numeric Combination Lock', 'Supreme®/SIGG™ CYD
>   1.0L Water Bottle', 'Waist Bag', 'Creeper Tee', 'Shatter Tee', '*FREE GIFT* Shower Cap', 'Christopher Walken King Of New York Tee', 'Dish
>   Towels (Set of 3)', 'Metal Lighter Holster', 'Bonded Logo Puffy
>   Jacket', 'Shoulder Bag', 'Chenille Hooded Sweatshirt', 'Backpack',
>   'Overdyed Beanie', 'Fruit Tee', 'Knot Tee', 'Organizer Pouch',
>   'Supreme®/Hanes® Leopard Boxer Briefs (2 Pack)', 'Duffle Bag', 'The
>   Real Shit L/S Tee', 'Red Rum Baseball Jersey', 'Supreme®/Hanes® Boxer
>   Briefs (4 Pack)', 'Kids Tee', 'Toy Uzi Inflatable Pillow', 'Apple
>   Hooded Sweatshirt', 'Spotlight Keychain', 'Supreme®/Hanes® Crew Socks
>   (4 Pack)', 'Taped Seam Jacket', 'Fronts Tee', 'Fruit Skateboard',
>   'Hard Goods Tee', 'Leda And The Swan Tee', 'Military Camp Cap',
>   'Leather Varsity Jacket', 'Patchwork Harrington Jacket', 'Formula
>   Sweatpant', 'Supreme®/Hanes® Tagless Tees (3 Pack)', 'I Make Shit
>   Happen Pin', 'Leda And The Swan Skateboard', 'Original Sin Tee',
>   'Clouds L/S Top', 'Racing Logo Work Shirt', 'Silk Camo Shirt',
>   'Libertad Gold Pendant', 'Blood Lust Ceramic Box', 'Piping Track
>   Jacket', 'Patchwork Mohair Cardigan', 'Supreme®/Hanes® Leopard Tagless
>   Tees (2 Pack)', 'Set In Logo Hooded Sweatshirt', 'Supreme®/Spitfire®
>   Classic Wheels (Set of 4)', 'Middle Finger To The World Tee', 'S/S
>   Pocket Tee', 'Supreme®/Independent® Truck', 'GORE-TEX S-Logo 6-Panel',
>   'Tag Logo Sweater', 'Tech L/S Tee', 'Shears Hooded Sweatshirt',
>   'Patchwork Cargo Pant', 'Stone Washed Slim Jean', 'Text Stripe New
>   Era®', 'Fuzzy Pile Trucker Jacket', 'D-Ring Trench Coat', 'Multi
>   Stripe S/S Top', 'Piping Track Pant', 'Work Pant', 'Tag Logo Beanie',
>   'Corduroy Compact Logo 6-Panel', 'Oxford Shirt', 'Set In Logo
>   Sweatpant', 'Stone Washed Black Slim Jean', 'Rose Buffalo Plaid
>   Shirt', 'Patchwork Bell Hat', 'Paisley Stripe L/S Top', 'Fuzzy Pile
>   Short', 'Tie Dye Ripstop Camp Cap', 'Taped Seam Pant', 'Washed Regular
>   Jean', 'Rigid Slim Jean', 'World 5-Panel', 'Signature Script Logo Camp
>   Cap', 'Motherfucker 6-Panel'], 'price': '\n
>   $48/£46\n
>   '}

Trying to get the format to look like this:

{title: Airbrushed Floral Skateboard, price: $48/£46, upvotes: 14218, downvotes: 1034}

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper relative XPath when using nested selectors, otherwise it will extract from the *entire* response:

```
'title': data.xpath(".//h2/text()").get(),
```

Refer to the documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths